# Zenject Why it needs to use InstallerPrefabs instead of my Installer? And what is InstallerPrefabs?

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

I've created the installer, created a prefab with the script and then attached it to the SceneContext. But When I run I get this error

"ZenjectException: Assert hit! Found prefab with name 'Installer' in the Installer property of Context 'SceneContext'.  You should use the property 'InstallerPrefabs' for this instead."

```
public class DefaultInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.Bind<IController>().To<RandomNumberController>().AsSingle();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> You should use the property 'InstallerPrefabs' for this instead

Have you considered referencing your prefab in the property `InstallerPrefabs` of SceneContext, instead of the property `Installer`?

2nd list in SceneContext's inspector, instead of 1st one:

[image: SceneContext]